# On jackpots in the Malaysian lottery

Tags: probability, gambling, lotteries

Below is the Jackpot in my home country. Based on my calculation, the probability of Jackpot 2 is higher than Jackpot 1 although Jackpot 1 has higher prize, which does not make sense to me.

Is my calculation wrong?

**Updated:**
Based on the comment and answers, it seems that the ticket bought is important on the probability calculation.

6 numbers needed to pick per ticket and no need to indicate which is the bonus number in ticket.

Ticket bought example: 3, 9, 13, 23, 33, 43 (no need to specify bonus number) 
Draw result: 3, 9, 13, 33, 40, 43  + 23 (bonus number)
Then you win jackpot 2

**Jackpot 1:**  
Winning criteria: 6 matching number out of 50 numbers
6 matching number: 50 choose 6 = 15890700
Probability: 1 in 15,890,700

**Jackpot 2:**  
Winning criteria: 5 matching number out of 50 numbers + 1 bonus number from the 50 numbers
5 matching number: 50 choose 5 = 2,118,760
1 bonus number: 50 - 6 = 44 numbers remaining

5 matching number + 1 bonus number = 2,118,760 x 44 = 93,225,440

Probability: 1 in 93,225,440

[image: Jackpot image]

Comment: Your probability for jackpot 2 is incorrect.  For example, it ignores the non-matching ball

Comment: @Henry would you be able to show  the correct calculation of jackpot 2?

Comment: Is the bonus ball number drawn from $50$ other random numbers or from the $44$ non-winning numbers wxcluding the $6$ winning numbers ?

Comment: @trueblueanil In this kind of lottery it is drawn from the $44$ so that near-misses of the main draw get an bonus chance to match their missing number. (There are others with an independent bonus draw, but typically from a smaller set of balls)

Comment: Either their answers are wrong or they can not explain well. I never claimed I can explain well.

Comment: I think OP must ask this question to the Malaysian lottery company. Because, in my opinion, we must make the answer both official and public.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your probability for Jackpot 1 is correct: $\frac{1}{50 \choose 6}=\frac{1}{15890700}$.

Your probability for Jackpot 2 is wrong.

There are ${50 \choose 7} = 99884400$ ways of choosing the six main balls and the bonus ball if you ignore their status ($7$ times more if you take account of the status).  Of these, $50-6=44$ will have the six numbers on the ticket, so the probability of winning either Jackpot 1 or Jackpot 2 is $\frac{44}{{50 \choose 7}}$ which is seven times the probability of winning Jackpot 1.

By subtraction, this make the probability of winning Jackpot 2 be six times the probability of winning Jackpot 1, i.e. $\frac{6}{50 \choose 6} = \frac1{2648450}$.

Approached a different way, the probability that the first six balls drawn have five of the numbers on the ticket and that the seventh ball matches the missing number is $\frac{{6 \choose 5}{50-6 \choose 1}}{50 \choose 6} \times \frac1{50-6 \choose 1}=\frac{6}{50 \choose 6}$ again.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. But I am confuse on the 7 times more if you take account of the status. Can you explain more about it? and what does take account of the status means?

Comment: @maths123 in the example given, you have $29$ as the bonus ball out of the balls drawn, but it could have been $3$ or $9$ or $14$ or $26$ or $45$ or $50$, so seven possibilities in all.  I did not use this in my calculations.

Comment: i have update the example of ticket bought as others have mentioned that it does affect the result. 6 numbers per ticket and do not need to indicate which is the bonus number

Comment: @maths123 So this link given by student https://lotteryguru.com/malaysia-lottery-results/my-star-toto-6-50 do not match with your game. You confirm ? Could you give a link to official rules of your game ?

Answer (score 1):

It appears you have to choose $7$ numbers

There are $6$ main winning numbers, $1$ bonus number and $43$ useless numbers,

Thus P(win jackpot 2) $ =\Large{\binom65\binom11\binom{43}1\over\binom{50}7} = {43\over 16\;647\;400}$

---

*OP finally says that only $6$ numbers are drawn*

Then P(win jackpot 2)
$=\Large\frac{\binom65\binom11}{\binom{50}6}= \frac1{2,648,450}$

Comment: Your answer is different from Henry and both of you has high reputation and score in probability subsection. Can you justify the answer with more explanation? I am in favor of Henry answer currently

Comment: @maths123: Well, the problem is that you have not specified the rules clearly, and I can't find it on the net. I have taken that *you can choose only $6$ balls,* and if $5$ happen to be from the $5$ prize winning, and one matches the bonus ball, you get the second prize. If the actual rules are different, please specify.

Comment: They are 7 draws from the pool of 50 balls. The bonus ball is taken from the same pool of 50 balls so they will not be repetitive number.

Comment: I@maths123: I understand that the winning numbers including bonus number(s) are drawn from the same $50$. The question I ask is how many numbers are on your ticket/choice .

Comment: @trueblueanil this is the site with 'rules': https://lotteryguru.com/malaysia-lottery-results/my-star-toto-6-50

Comment: @ maths123: It appears that you have to choose $7$ numbers, so I have reworked computations accordingly.

Comment: I can't access the site given by @student, I believe it is similar system as for a 10 draw in this link. https://i.stack.imgur.com/BYeut.png

Comment: @trueblueanil i have update the example of ticket bought. 6 numbers per ticket and do not need to indicate which is the bonus number