# Odds of winning the Malaysian lottery [part 2]

Tags: probability, gambling, lotteries

<sub>[Part 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4646203/)</sub>

---

Jackpot Bonus number: remaining of number inside the 8 matching number.

**Updated:**
Per ticket is 8 numbers and no need to specify which is bonus number

**Grand Prize**: 8 matching number from 36 numbers
Probability: 1 in (36 choose 8)

**2nd prize**: 7 matching number from 36 numbers + (any 1 of 2 bonus numbers)

**3rd prize**: 7 matching numbers from 36 numbers
Probability: 1 in (36 choose 7)

**4h prize**: 6 matching number from 36 numbers + (any 1 of 2 bonus numbers)

What is the probability of winning 2nd prize and 4th prize respectively?

[image: Lottery Winning Condition]

Comment: I guess a lottery ticket  just asks to choose any 10 numbers from 36 possible. Am I correct? This is the first time I hear about bonus numbers and they confuse me a bit.

Comment: I now think that my assumption is not correct and only 8 numbers should be chosen.

Comment: Your answer for question 3 is wrong ; you already had explanations for very similar question in the other topic.

Comment: @kludg Per ticket is pick 8 numbers and no need to specify which is bonus number

Comment: Hi! To avoid down-votes and close-votes, please provide us some context for this question, such as: (a) Is this homework? (b) If so, what course are you taking? (c) What specific topic are you covering at the moment? (d) What do you know that you think might be connected? (e) If you're stuck, what are you stuck on? For example, do you know what to apply, but don't know how to apply it, or do you not know what to apply? Please put these facts in your original post, not as responses to this comment, as comments may be deleted without warning.

Comment: Can you give us the link of this lottery company? Maybe, we understand the lotto from their pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Divide number into $8$ winning, $2$ bonus, $26$ useless

Win $2nd$ prize = $\Large{\binom87\binom21\binom{26}0\over\binom{36}8}\approx1\; in\; 1,891, 271$

You should be able to work out $4th$ prize similarly as

$\Large{\binom86\binom21\binom{26}1\over\binom{36}8}$

Comment: The condition is they are 10 draws out of 36. The 2 bonus numbers will come from the same 36 numbers, thus they will not be repetitive of numbers

Comment: @maths123: But will your ticket have $8$ numbers or $10$ numbers ?

Comment: 10 number version added

Comment: I think this version includes the first prize. That is why I used 25 possible values for the "free" numbers in the 2nd prize calculation.

Comment: @kludg: I don't understand, $8$ are prime, $2$ are subprime and the remaining $26$ are of no use. As I see it, there is a clear trifurcation.

Comment: @trueblueanil I guess you are right and it is too late for me to calculate. Anyway I think that OP meant choosing 8 numbers, it makes more sense.

Comment: @trueblueanil Per ticket is pick 8 numbers and no need to specify which is bonus number

Comment: Well, I wish the rules were clear to start with ! I am amending.

Comment: @trueblueanil l I seen your updated answer. The results that your provided is not logical. Let start with probability of hitting 6 matching number, which is 1 in (36 choose 6) , that is  1 in 1, 947, 792. Your calculation indicates that the probability of hitting 7 number + 1 bonus is (1 in 1, 891, 271) and 6 number + 1 bonus is (1 in 20, 783). It make no sense to me that probability of hitting 6 number is lower than 7 number + 1 bonus and 6 number + 1 bonus

Comment: For hitting all 6 and any of the remaining, 28, $Pr = {\binom86\binom{28}2\over\binom{36}8}= 1\;in\; 2859$, you have to account for every number you have chosen

Comment: NY State Lotto works by "$6$ winning numbers and a bonus number are randomly selected from $59$ numbered balls".  The $3rd$ Prize level states that you have matched $5$ numbers, and not the bonus number.  Your chances of winning the 3rd Prize level is $1:144,414.98$.  ([NY State Lotto Chances Page][1]) My calculation of reciprocal of $\binom65\binom{52}1 / \binom{59}6$ matches it **exactly** These are very well known (at least to me) calculations involving the hypergeometric distribution